# How to get the list of binutils available in my system?

Tags: binary, binutils

I want to know the list of binary tools available in my system.where are these binutils located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the programs from the binutils package are located in `/usr/bin`. They are:

```
addr2line ar as c++filt dwp elfedit gold gprof ld ld.bfd ld.gold nm objcopy objdump ranlib readelf size strings strip
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and use this command to find where binutils files have been installed:

> cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/binutils.list | less

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command in a terminal:

```
dpkg-query -L binutils | grep -oP "/usr/bin/\K([a-zA-Z\.-_\+]+$)" | sort
addr2line
ar
as
c++filt
dwp
elfedit
gold
gprof
ld
ld.bfd
ld.gold
nm
objcopy
objdump
ranlib
readelf
size
strings
strip
```

It returns all files installed in `/usr/bin/` provided by the `binutils` package.

The same list can also be found on http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/binutils/filelist.

Comment: @karel Good catch! Thank you. I fixed the regexp. We now have the same list (`addr2line` was missing IIRC ;), +1